# Access to Glassfish folders from Java Spring MVC 3 application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, glassfish-3

I have folder `.../domains/domain1/images` on my Glassfish server. In my Java Spring controller I have method which saves uploaded image on server:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String sendData(@RequestParam("north") Double north, @RequestParam("east") Double east, @RequestParam("phone") String phone, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {

    if (!"image/jpg".equals(file.getContentType()) && !"image/jpeg".equals(file.getContentType())) {
        return "redirect:/form";
    }

    Date date = new Date();
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    String filename = ts.toString();
    filename = filename.replaceAll("\\s", "_");
    String path = imagePath + filename;

    File imageFile = new File(path);
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file.getInputStream());
        image = ImageTransformer.scaleByWidth(image, imageWidth);
        imageFile.createNewFile();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", imageFile);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "redirect:/form";
    }

    Marker m = new Marker();
    m.setNorth(north);
    m.setEast(east);
    m.setPhone(phone);
    m.setUrl(filename);

    markerService.add(m);

    return "redirect:/start";
}
```

How I should set my `imagePath` variable to make it happen? Should I change some default path in server configurations?

Thanks in advance.

**UPD**: Don't want to deal with absolute paths in Java application, if possible.

Comment: I suggest you to reconsider the path for your images storage to be outside of your GlassFish (or another) application server. It would be better having a */path/for/your/images/* instead.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza But `imagePath` should be absolute in this case?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can I create some property on the server (folder path) and use it in the application? Don't want to change my application when deploying.

Comment: The best option would be to have a property with the absolute path to the folder where you will save your images. Make sure the folder has enough permissions to let your Java web application manipulate files there. By the way, your absolute path must be */like/this/example/path* instead of *D:\evil\windows\path\that\leads\to\problems*

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out the difference. Do you mean url in the first case? My Glassfish is on Linux, so, first path lokks like valid absolute path.

Comment: No, it's not an URL, it's an absolute path. I said it since some developers work on Windows for development and deploy the products on Linux and have the path problems.

Comment: Hm, thanks. So, now I set the path as `../images/`, because Glassfish default path is `.../domains/domain1/config`. Maybe it's bad practice, but now it works :)
I want to store images in Glassfish folder, because my database is in it by default (but not in domain).

Answer (score 0):

In WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml, try adding alternate doc root(s) for your resources:

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/yourapp</context-root>
  ...
  <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/images/*  dir=/path/to/your/images"/>
  <property name="alternatedocroot_2" value="from=/sounds/*  dir=/path/to/your/sounds"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Then, in your application code you can use paths relative to your application root.